# how to access an shared forder with guest user

Tags: shared-folders

[image: picture]

Like the picture show. On ubuntu, how can i access the shared location with guest user?

The tow window which i want is taked from macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the next `smb.conf` configuration:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    netbios name = UBUNTU-POWERSPEC
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 10240
    security = user
    map to guest = Bad Password
    getwd cache = yes
    guest account = nobody
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    server signing = auto
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    local master = yes

    vfs objects = acl_xattr
    map acl inherit = yes
    store dos attributes = yes

    winbind nss info = template
    winbind enum users = Yes
    winbind enum groups = Yes
    winbind use default domain = yes

    client use spnego = yes
    client ntlmv2 auth = yes

    encrypt passwords = yes

    local master = No
    hide dot files = No
    allow insecure wide links = yes
    store dos attributes = yes


[sambashare]
    path = /home/user/sambashare
    comment = sambashare on Ubuntu
    directory mask = 0755
    create mode = 0777
    read only = no
    available = yes
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    public = yes
    locking = no
    strict locking = no
```

As you can see, in `[global]` section you have `guest account = nobody`, `usershare allow guests = Yes`. In share's configuration you have `guest ok = yes`, `public = yes`, `writable = yes` and so on. Also make sure your share's folder has write permissions for anybody.